# Apache Hive: How to use Unicode character (with octal above 177) as field delim

Tags: hadoop, unicode, utf-8, hive

in our use case we are getting UTF-8 text data that is formatted like this:

```
Data1§Data2
Data3§Data4
```

Now we would like to have Data1 and Data3 in one column, Data2 and Data4 in one column in Apache Hive. Sounds simple.

However, we are not able to specify the § character (which is unicode U+00A7 "Section Sign" see [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct)) as field delimiter.

We have tried the following ways, nothing leading to acceptable results.

1) Using the normal fields terminated by approach

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '§'
```

Returning (notice the ? attached to each cell, in other clients the unicode sign for a not recognized sign)

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| test.column1       | test.column2          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| Data1?             | Data2?                |
| Data3?             | Data4?                |
+--------------------+--------------------+-
```

or for octal representation

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\247'
```

or

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\304\247'
```

Returning:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| test.column1       | test.column2          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| Data1?Data2        | NULL                  |
| Data3?Data4        | NULL                  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
```

2) Using  RegexSerDe

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "^([^\\]]+)\\\247([^\\]]+)$")
```

(Changing the field delimiter e.g. to / in some test source data and using \057 (octal for / ) yields the correct results, but changing the source data is not feasible for us.)

or

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "^([^\\]]+)\\$([^\\]]+)$")
```

(In a describe formatted table statement this yields:

```
input.regex  ^([^\\]]+)\\\uFFFD\uFFFD([^\\]]+)$
```

where \uFFFD is the unicode representation for a not recognized sign)

The result of a SELECT is always the same:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| test.column1       | test.column2          |
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
| NULL               | NULL                  |
| NULL               | NULL                  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--+
```

**My research so far indicates the following:**

1) Hive is not able to use non-printable ASCII characters that hive a higher octal number than 177. Pointers to this are to my surprise in some other code [here](https://github.com/simplegeo/hadoop/blob/master/cloudera/patches/0165-MAPREDUCE-1310.-CREATE-TABLE-statements-for-Hive-do-.patch) on github where is says:

> Hive can specify delimiter characters in the form '\ooo' where ooo is
>   a three-digit octal number between 000 and 177.

2) Also I have found evidence that only one-byte characters can be used as field delim [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_2.1.2/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_create_table.html) in the documentation of BigSQL (but not in the official documentation) where it says:

> Delimiters must be single-byte characters

and as to my research § (unicode U+00A7) is a 2-byte character (11000010:10100111)

**Does this mean I can not use this delimiter or is there any other ways to use it?**

Small Update, if this will stay unsolved and somebody needs it:

I tried the following approach of staging the data as a one-column table and then translating § to , (comma) and then to split it by comma. This works for small sample data, but fails for my larger production table with 200+ columns with an Error.

```
select
split(a.textcolumn, '\\,')[0] as column1
,split(a.textcolumn, '\\,')[1] as column2
from
(select translate(textcolumn, '§', ',') as textcolumn from database.stage) a;
```

Here is the Error:

SQL Error: java.io.IOException:     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating translate(stagingstring, '§', ';')
  java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating translate(stagingstring, '§', ';')
    java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating translate(stagingstring, '§', ';')
      org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating translate(stagingstring, '§', ';')
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:Error evaluating translate(stagingstring, '§', ';')
          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null

Update 2:

The approach above works, but if the source data is not clean (has other UTF-8 issues) it will throw the above error.

Comment: are you copy pasting the section symbol  when writing create table script? try to use `Alt+0167` combination to write section symbol. I have faced the similar issue.

Comment: Does not help, also when using the ASCII table of Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in my update to the question above. However this will throw and error if the data is not clean or contains other problematic characters I found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your table with

`Fields Terminated by '-89'`

DECIMAL code for 'section sign' is 167.

```
167 - 256 = -89
```

This -89 should be your delimiter. Hive allows delimiters in range of -127 to 127.

For further read following snippet from Cloudera.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html

*Note: The CREATE TABLE clauses FIELDS TERMINATED BY, ESCAPED BY, and LINES TERMINATED BY have special rules for the string literal used for their argument, because they all require a single character. You can use a regular character surrounded by single or double quotation marks, an octal sequence such as '\054' (representing a comma), or an integer in the range '-127'..'128' (with quotation marks but no backslash), which is interpreted as a single-byte ASCII character. Negative values are subtracted from 256; for example, FIELDS TERMINATED BY '-2' sets the field delimiter to ASCII code 254, the "Icelandic Thorn" character used as a delimiter by some data formats.*

Answer (score 1):

I know that is kind of a cold case, but that issue may be solved using a [MultiDelimitSerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe).

Actually, Hive default SerDe (known as LazySimpleSerDe) only supports single-byte delimiter. As [alpcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073584/alpcoder) said, that is not documented. You need to read the source code to figure it.

[MultiDelimitSerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe) was designed to support multi-characters delimiters. Fortunately, it supports any multi-byte character.